# Когда стоит использовать «один из», а когда «одно из»?

Tags: выбор-слов

Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно:

> Твёрдое топливо — одно из видов топлива

или

> Твёрдое топливо — один из видов топлива

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Твёрдое топливо — один (вид) из видов топлива.**

Обычно согласование делается со слово ***вид***, например: Бактерии ― **один из видов** микробов. Практически в Нацкорпусе встречается только этот вариант.

Согласование в ср. роде (приведен один  пример):  И действительно, **ни одно** (наказание)  из видов альтернативного наказания...не получило распространения. [Александр Михайлов. Правосудие стоит дорого (2003) // «Российская газета», 2003.05.15]